# Notification Using Task Scheduling Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, task

**This is my DeviceNotification Command**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Notifications\WeatherNotification;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Zttp\Zttp;
use Notification;




class DeviceNotification extends Command
{


protected $signature = 'Device:Notification';


protected $description = 'Making notification everyday with per device(User) with weather APi';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}


public function handle()
{

    $allusers = DB::table('users')->where('account_type', 'farm_manager')->get();

    $apiKey = 'cde1hjdsgfhbssb051njidsn65c90';

    foreach ($allusers as $userone) {

        $Lat = DB::table('users')->where('user_id', $userone->user_id)->value('x_loc');
        $Lat = number_format($Lat, 4, '.', ',');

        $Long = DB::table('users')->where('user_id', $userone->user_id)->value('y_loc');
        $Long = number_format($Long, 4, '.', ',');

        $response = Zttp::get("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/$apiKey/$Lat,$Long?units=ca");
        $data = $response->json();

        $rainprediction =  100 * $data['daily']['data']['0']['precipProbability'];

        $tomoprediction =  100 * $data['daily']['data']['1']['precipProbability'];

        $dayafteroprediction =  100 * $data['daily']['data']['2']['precipProbability'];


        if ($rainprediction > 70.0) {
            $msg = "There is " . $rainprediction . "% probability of rainfall today.";
        } elseif ($rainprediction > 50.0 && $rainprediction < 70.0) {
            $msg = "There is " . $rainprediction . "% probability of rainfall today.";
        } else {
            $msg = "There is " . $rainprediction . "% probability of rainfall today.";
        }
        if ($tomoprediction > 70.0) {
           $msgtomoprediction = "There is " . $tomoprediction . "% probability of  Tmorrow.";
        } elseif ($tomoprediction > 50.0 && $tomoprediction < 70.0) {
          $msgtomoprediction = "There is " . $tomoprediction . "% probability of Tomorrow.";
        } else {
          $msgtomoprediction = "There is " . $tomoprediction . "% probability of Tomorrow.";
        }
        if ($dayafteroprediction > 70.0)
         {
            $msgdayafteroprediction = "There is " . $dayafteroprediction . "%  After Tomorrow.";
          } elseif ($dayafteroprediction > 50.0 && $dayafteroprediction < 70.0) { 
           $msgdayafteroprediction = "There is " . $dayafteroprediction . "% probability Tomorrow.";
        } else {
         $msgdayafteroprediction = "There is " . $dayafteroprediction . "%  Tomorrow.";
        }

        $user_id = $userone->farm_id;
        $message_notification = array(
            'today' => $msg,
            'Tomorrow' => $msgtomoprediction,
            'Day-After' => $msgdayafteroprediction,
        );



        //$userone->notify(new WeatherNotification($user_id, $message_notification));
        Notification::send($userone, new WeatherNotification($user_id, $message_notification));
    }
}
}
```

**This is my Notification**

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use  App\User;

 class WeatherNotification extends Notification
{
use Queueable;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected $user_id;
protected $message_notification;

public function __construct($user_id, $message_notification)
{
    //
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
    $this->message_notification = $message_notification;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}


public function toArray($notifiable)
{

    return [
        //

        'farm_id' =>  $this->user_id,
        'weather_notification' =>  $this->message_notification,
    ];
}
}
```

I am getting 
   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined method stdClass::notify()
this **Error** when i run the code with    **$userone->notify(new WeatherNotification($user_id, $message_notification));**

and

this:
**Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined method stdClass::routeNotificationFor()**

when I run it using this **Notification::send($userone, new WeatherNotification($user_id, $message_notification));**

Answer (score 0):

Use the notifiable trait on your user model.

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
```

Here is its description in docs. [using-the-notifiable-trait](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait)

Also Use User Model to retrieve the users instead of Query Builder

```
User::where('account_type', 'farm_manager')->get();
```

Comment: Tried that! Same Error

Comment: You are actually using the Query Builder to retrieve users that's why method notify is not defined.

So Use 
User::
instead of
DB::table('users')